# Multiple splash screens in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, splash-screen

I am trying to create two splash screens in Android studio. My first splash screen works fine but my second splash screen does not.

How can I create a second splash screen?

Here is My code for the first splash screen below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class SplashScreen extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread myThread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
                Intent startMainScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(startMainScreen);
                finish();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    myThread.start();
}
```

}

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
            />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

**Layout code**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@drawable/cls2">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you give me a little more detail?

Comment: I want to view another splash screen as soon as the the first one is gone

Comment: Is the second one the main screen or will the room close and open another screen?

Comment: The second splash screen will close and proceed to the main screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new splash activity 
now, instead of doing an intent to MainActivty 
in the first splash intent to the second splash 
and finally intent to MainActivity from the second splash.

The code for the second splash is identical to the one you already have.

Comment: I am on my phone! tell me if you don't understand something

Comment: I have already tried this and my app crashes after the first splash screen. 


  try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent startMainScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplasScreen2.class);
                    startActivity(startMainScreen);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Comment: I do not get an error log. It tells me Unfortunately App_Name has stopped. Unless the error logs are somewhere else where I can't see them. Sorry I am a little new to Android studio

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lyubo.clubscene/com.example.lyubo.clubscene.SplasScreen2}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>


 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>

Comment: is there a reason for inheriting MainActiviyy

Comment: I fixed the problem. The problem was that one of my images was too large